# How to print British Pound Sign £ on Thermal receipt printer 80mm?

Tags: c#

I am trying to print Pound symbol ( £ ) on thermal receipt printer 80mm but its showing (?) mark. I am using raw printer helper c#.

```
    StringBuilder print = new StringBuilder();
    string barcode = "1234567890";
    char commandGS = '\x1D';
    char linefeed = '\x0A';
    char esc = '\x1B';
    char commandFontSize = '\x21';
    char commandk = '\x6B';
    char code128 = '\x69';

    print.Append("£200.\r\n");
    print.Append(code128);
    print.Append(barcode.Length);
    print.Append(barcode);
    string printJob = print.ToString();
    RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter("PrinterName", printJob);
```

Comment: I don't believe you... until I see your code.

Comment: please, consider adding the code ;D

Comment: Hi guys, I have added my existing code please check.

Answer (score 2):

If you print raw onto thermal printer, then your symbols not showing up is probably a font issue. That is, the font installed on the printer does not contain the symbol you are trying to print.

Depending on the model of that printer, you will have to install a font that has the symbols you want to use. Check manufacturer's site and documentation of the printer, sometimes installing new fonts or missing codepages is explained there.

Also, check that you're using the correct codepage and the code of £ symbol you are printing is the same as the code that the font on the printer has. Sometimes in thermal printers the default font has some less essential characters "moved" a bit to make the font lighter.

Some further info:

https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/knowledge-articles/ait/downloading-and-using-fonts-on-zebra-zpl-printers.html

https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/88407/how-to-access-printer-built-in-fonts/

https://sites.psu.edu/symbolcodes/windows/charmap/

Pound character £ has two versions:
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm?q=+%C2%A3&preview=entity

- http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a3/index.htm
- http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ffe1/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
        StringBuilder print = new StringBuilder();
        string barcode = "1234567890";
        char commandGS = '\x1D';
        char linefeed = '\x0A';
        char esc = '\x1B';
        char commandFontSize = '\x21';
        char commandk = '\x6B';
        char code128 = '\x69';

        print.Append("£200.\r\n");
        print.Append(code128);
        print.Append(barcode.Length);
        print.Append(barcode);
        string printJob = print.ToString();
        RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter("PrinterName", printJob);
```

Comment: please see my existing code. Let me know where I m doing mistake.